# How manage Resolution in gwt?

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

I am developing a web application in GWT. 
In the base HTML page I am using htlm `<table>` tags like `<tr>`,`<td>` and I set the table  size at 990px, because the panels used in gwt are measured in pixels(i.e. AbsolutePanel).
This works ok in 1024 but on any other resolution, does will this create a problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going about it the wrong way. gwt-ext is long dead.

Current Choices - Pure GWT UiBinder , Pure GWT LayoutPanel, Sencha GXT, Vaadin.

Using AbsolutePanel for building entire screens are not recommended. To get screens working across multiple resolution you need to start here https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels

Also ensure you understand the concepts related to LayoutPanel and RootLayoutPanel.

Comment: According to u, whole code converted into choices(UIBinder etc) but really this not easy... any other way??

Comment: Pure GWT LayoutPanel using relative positioning and % width/height. AbsolutePanels and Fixed height/width in pixes never relate to Responsive resolution independent UI Design.

Answer (score 0):

When ever and where ever ,to escape from the height width problems regardless of resolutions..

please consider to Use in  '%'. It is better to avoid static pixel numbers in the code .

Comment: ultimately every panel is an widget ..widget class setWidth("X%") is acceptable .

Comment: i just check AbsolutePanel panel = new AbsolutePanel();
  panel.setWidth("80%");
  panel.add(new Button("suresh test"));
  RootPanel.get().add(panel);   successfully got the 80% width to the panel ..

Comment: AbsolutePanel we have to use to add multiple widget at particular position but when i am using panel.add(button,10,40); in percentage(%) it create problem.

Comment: so we can go for int height =Window.getClientHeight();  int width=Window.getClientWidth();   hope the above lines give some hint